# Create dictionary entry for each letter of a word and its location

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm attempting to fill a dictionary with tuples in the form (n,l).

The value associated with key(n, l)is the set of words in the file that contain the letter l at position n.

For example, if the file had the word word 'Python', I would want the function to output:   `c_dict(0, "p"), c_dict(1, "y"), c_dict(2,"t") and so on.`

So far, I have words from the text file being added, but I'm not sure where to continue from there. Could anyone provide some suggestions?

```
c_dict= {}
def fill_completions():   
    for line in open('file.txt'):
        data=line.strip().split()
        c_dict[data[0]]=tuple(data[1:])
    print(c_dict)
```

I am using Python 3.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `enumerate(iterable)` to get tuples of `(index, item)` in an iterable.

```
for i, char in enumerate('python'):
   print i, char

#0, 'p'
#1, 'y'
..
#5, 'n'


>>>dict(enumerate('python')) 
{0:'p', 1:'y', ... 5:'n'}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped. I'm now trying to use an open text file and do this for every word in the file. Any suggestions?